# Java Inheritance: Restrict List to Subclass Objects

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance, collections

Let's assume I have 3 classes: Car, Convertible and Garage.

Car:

```
public class Car {    
    private String name;
    private String color;

    public Car(String name, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }    
    //Getters
}
```

Convertible inherits from Car:

```
public class Convertible extends Car{
    private boolean roof;

    public Convertible(String name, String color, boolean roof) {
        super(name, color);
        this.roof = roof;
    }

    public boolean isRoof() {
        return roof;
    }
}
```

Garage stores a list of Cars:

```
public class Garage {
    private int capacity;
    private List<Car> cars = new LinkedList<Car>();

    //Setter for capacity
}
```

How could I create a subclass of `Garage` called `ConvertibleGarage` that can only store Convertibles?

Comment: It is a strange garage with no public methods other than the constructor.

Comment: Does it have to be a subclass? You could just make Garage Generic and allow for the creation of an Garage<Convertible> object instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a little bit of generics:

```
public class Garage<T extends Convertible> {
    private int capacity;
    private List<T> cars = new LinkedList<T>();

    public Garage(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
}
```

This means when you instantiate a `Garage` you now have to include a parameter type that is a Convertible or child of it.

```
Garage<Convertible> cGarage = new Garage<>();
```

Comment: What about `new Garage<Car>`?

Comment: @JinKwon The OP asked for a garage that can only store `Convertible`, so `Car` would not be a `Convertible`, but `Convertible` would be a `Car`

Answer (score 5):

Generics will help here.

Make the `Garage` class generic `Garage<T extends Car>`, where a `T` is a car type it can store. Rewrite the `cars` list to a generic view `List<T>` as well.

Then, a `Garage<Convertible>` is going to be your "ConvertibleGarage".

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to make a second Garage class, you can use Generics :

```
public class Garage<T extends Car> {

   private int capacity;

   private List<T> cars;

   public Garage() {
       this.cars = new LinkedList<>();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Garage<Convertible> garConv = new Garage<>();
       garConv.cars.add(new Convertible("", "", true));

       Garage<Car> garCar = new Garage<>();
       garCar.cars.add(new Car("", ""));
   }
}
```

With this only class you can have a garage for car and a one for convertible

Comment: You last sentence is simply **wrong** advise. From a "what happens at runtime" perspective there isnt much difference anyway. And when you *know* that your field should be init'ed - it is perfectly fine to go for `private final List<T> cars = new ArrayList<>()` for example. That is even the **preferred** solution.

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry i've not understand all you said :/, so what the difference, and why "preferred solution" ?

Comment: OK, lets be precise. To a certain degree this is "style only" . The more important aspect is: make sure to use `final` where possible. So that the compiler tells you about init'ing your field. When you have ONE constructor, it doesnt matter much *where* you init. But assume you have 3 constructors - why would you write "new ArrayList" three times; instead of just doing it once?!

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have explained, you solve your problem by making your `Garage` class *[generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)* - and therefore allowing any instance of `Garage` to deal with exactly **one** kind of cars.

But what is missing so far: this is not "an option" to solve your problem - this is simply "the way to go here". Your idea of using **inheritance** is "plain wrong". Meaning: when people start with object oriented design, they assume that inheritance is the answer to everything. And actually that is *not* true. You are rather careful about creating an `extends` relation between two classes.

And especially when talking about containers - classes that "contain" other objects - then **generics** is your first thought!